# A corollary from the fact that every symmetric polynomial could be written as a polynomial in the elementary ones

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, symmetric-polynomials

The following is stated in the book *Abstract Algebra* by Robert Ash, the book is free and the relevant [chapter could be seen here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter6.pdf). In 6.1.4. it is shown that every symmetric polynomial could be expressed as a polynomial in the elementary symmetric polynomials, and from this in 6.1.5. the following corollary is derived ($F$ denotes a field):

> If $g$ is a polynomial in $F[X]$ and $f(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ is any symmetric polynomial in the roots $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$, then $f \in F[X]$.
>
> *Proof.* We may assume without loss of generality that $g$ is monic. Then in a splitting field of $g$ we have
>   $$
>  g(X) = (X-\alpha_1)\ldots (X-\alpha_n) = X^n - e_1 X^{n-1} + \ldots + (-1)^n e_n.
> $$
>   By (6.1.4), $f$ is a polynomial in the $e_i$, and since the $e_i$ are simply $\pm$ the coefficients of $g$, the coefficients of $f$ are in $F$. $\square$

I cannot make sense of it, why should $f$ be even a polynomial in $X$? Where does the $X$ comes from? I see that it is a polynomial in the $e_i$ (which themselve depend on the $\alpha_i$), so that it could be written as a polynomial in terms of $\pm$ the coefficients of $g$ (viewing them as indeterminates), so if we view them as values we get elements from $F$, i.e. that would give $f \in F$ after "plugin in" the values of the coefficients. But this does not makes any sense either?

Comment: Over any field $F$, if $g(X) = \prod_{i=1}^n (X-\alpha_i) \in F[X]$ is a separable polynomial (so the $\alpha_i \in \overline{F}^{sep}$) and $f(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n,X) \in F[\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n][X]$ is invariant under permutation of the $\alpha_i$, then $f \in F[X]$.

Comment: @reuns Do you think that the book missed to state that $X$ should be also an indeterminante in $f$?

Comment: I don't know but what I wrote is the answer to your question :) If you don't like symmetric polynomials then let $K = F[\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n]$ so that $K/F$ is a Galois extension and with $G = \text{Gal}(K/ F)$ then $F = K^G = \{ a \in K, \forall \sigma \in G, \sigma(a) = a\}$ the fixed field of $G$.

Comment: @reuns Okay, but I cannot make sense of your proof, could you please give a few more details why this proves the claim...

Comment: Galois theory : $f \in K[X]$  and its coefficients are invariant under $G$ thus $f \in K^G[X] = F[X]$. Otherwise use the decomposition in elementary symmetric polynomials. Also when $g$ is non-separable it gets more complicated !

Comment: @reuns the coefficients are invariant because they are the elementary symmetric polynomials in the $\alpha_i$'s? Maybe you could write this as an answer...

Comment: That's the assumption : $f(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n,X) =f(\sigma(\alpha_1),\ldots,\sigma(\alpha_n),X)$. If it is invariant under every permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ then you can use the symmetric polynomials (expressed in terms of the coefficients of $g$), if it is invariant under each $\sigma \in G = Aut(K/F)$ then you can use the Galois theory.

Comment: I think it's a typo